# Escape certain characters in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, hive

This is my below shell script which I am using to query the hive tables and I saved this file as `test4.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE_YEST_FORMAT1=`perl -e 'use POSIX qw(strftime); print strftime "%Y-%m-%d",localtime(time()- 3600*96);'`
echo $DATE_YEST_FORMAT1

QUERY1=`hive -e "
set mapred.job.queue.name=hdmi-technology;
SELECT split(ckey, '\\|') AS t1
                    ,created_time
                FROM (
                    SELECT CONCAT (
                            buyer_id
                            ,'|'
                            ,item_id
                            ) AS ckey
                        ,created_time
                    FROM dw_checkout_trans
                    WHERE to_date(from_unixtime(cast(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_time) AS BIGINT))) = '$DATE_YEST_FORMAT1' distribute BY ckey sort BY ckey
                        ,created_time DESC
                    ) a
                WHERE rank(ckey) < 1;"`
```

**Problem Statement:-**

I am running the above shell script as-

```
bash -x test4.sh
```

If you see this line in the above `hive sql query`:

```
**SELECT split(ckey, '\\|') AS t1**.
```

Do I need to escape slash sign to make it to work in shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside backticks and double quotes, you basically need to double your backslashes, yes.  If a backslash is not a known escape sequence, it will be preserved, though.

```
bash$ echo "foo\bar"
foo\bar

bash$ echo "foo\\bar"
foo\bar

bash$ echo "split(ckey, '\\|')"
split(ckey, '\|')
```

So if you want `hive` to see a double backslash there, you will need to put four backslashes in the Bash script.

See further e.g. http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_03.html